# Table 'cart' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql

I tried to execute this query in phpmyadmin:

```
DELETE FROM `cart` WHERE cart_id = (SELECT cart_id FROM cart WHERE cart_user_id = 1 AND cart_item_id = 1 LIMIT 1)
```

but it gave me this error:

#1093 - Table 'cart' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: The error is correct. You can't select from the table you are deleting. Are you using PHP? You could run a `select` prior, unclear why you would need the sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need is:

```
DELETE FROM cart WHERE cart_user_id = 1 AND cart_item_id = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Andy, in my opinion, when editing a question you should not edit the command originally used; adding the space to make `=1` in to the slightly more readable `= 1` didn't change anything in this case, but sometimes a subtle syntax difference does matter. Good job on the rest of the edit and your answer.